# how can i add iframe code in joomla 3.2 in article manager?

Tags: iframe, joomla, joomla3.2

Hello i am new user of joomla 3.2.1
My iframe code not working in article editor.I also set editor setting and remove iframe that block automatically and now code not remove from article editor but it's not working in my website page.So,Please.. help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

[Include HTML or PHP codes into Joomla article](http://www.walkswithme.net/how-to-include-html-or-php-codes-into-joomla-article).

This question asked many times in the forum different way!

Comment: I don't even think this is necessary. I believe if you open the TinyMCE plugin in the Joomla backend and remove `iframe` from the tags that aren't allowed, you can simply input it in your article

Comment: This works in 2019: https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/faq/editor/iframe-removed-on-saving